# Setting up Wordpress Theme - Post content makes screen scroll

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Newbie question.

I'm just learning how to create WordPress themes.

Every-time I start a new project, the texts of posts scroll off the screen rather than wrapping to it.

See the picture attached.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNtau.png)

I haven't yet added any CSS. 
I've added the HTML doc header to the Header file and closed it in the footer file.

Am I missing something here? When I watch tutorial videos everyone else's post/page content is wrapped to the screen with no side-scrolling.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 0):

You can use main `<div>`

```
<div class="container">
    // Your Content
</div>
```

in your `<body>` and give the CSS of width, padding and margin as your requirement. Like below

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```